# push string from ajax to array for AmCharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, tcp

Hi I'm noob in javascript and I need your help. I want to draw chart with real time data from my MCU. But don't know how to push string into array. In this code Array (chart.dataProvider) is still undefined

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",{

...

"dataProvider":[],
});

function f() { 
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var value = this.responseText;        //get the response data as a string            
     //  value= {cat: 1, c1: 2, c2: 3};    //this metod draw my chart but i want RT data...
     alert(value); //output: {cat: 1, c1: 2, c2: 3}
     chart.dataProvider.push(value);
     chart.validateData();
                                                      }};
     req.open("GET", "http://", true);
     req.send();
     }
```

also it works too:

```
chart.dataProvider.push({ cat: 1, c1: 2, c2: 3 });
```

but how to push data from  XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: As per your code, dataProvider is not a property of chart here, so chart.dataProvider should not be correct

Comment: But when i put this:
value= {cat: 1, c1: 2, c2: 3};
into my code it works and draw chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys i found very easy solution:

```
var input = this.responseText;
alert (input);   // output: 1category500fColumn1000sColumn
var i = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('category'));
var ii = input.substring(input.indexOf('category')+8, input.indexOf('fColumn'));
var iii = input.substring(input.indexOf('fColumn')+7, input.indexOf('sColumn'));
     chart.dataProvider.push({
     cat: i,
     c1: ii,
     c2: iii});
```

so it should be something like this:

```
        {cat: 1,
         c1: 500,
         c2: 1000}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize it `chart.dataProvider = []` before pushing new values.

If this is problematic - You could also check if it's undefined, and if so - initialize it `chart.dataProvider = chart.dataProvider? chart.dataProvider : []`

lastly, if your question was regarding the ajax operation - try to use Promises or callback to wait with the push operation.

Hope it helps